# Find by unique key in xsd?

Tags: .net, xsd

Im using xsd:unique in an xsd generated code.  How do I get an item by the unique key?

I just need the Rows.Find method, but for unique keys in addition to the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the output of XSD.EXE, it pays no attention to `xsd:unique`.